# How can I fill and submit a form after logging in using Python 2.7?

Tags: javascript, python, forms, python-requests

I'm pretty new to Python and HTML language and I'm asking your help to do the following  task (first post ever on Stackoverflow ever for me...).
I have to scrape all customers' reviews from my firm's  web tool (unfortunately not accessible from outside).
I successfully perform the login to the web tool using the following script:

```
import requests, lxml.html

s = requests.session()
login = s.get('http://bp-webtools1.otto.boreus.de/tools/login#')
login_html = lxml.html.fromstring(login.text)
hidden_inputs = login_html.xpath(r'//form//input[@type="hidden"]')   
#print hidden_inputs
form = {x.attrib['name']: x.attrib['value'] for x in hidden_inputs}
#print form
form2 = {'username': 'myusername',
         'password': 'mypassword',
         'utf': '&#x2713;',
         'authenticity_token': form["authenticity_token"], 
         'mandant': 'bp',
         'commit': 'Anmelden'
}
print form2
response = s.post('http://bp-webtools1.otto.boreus.de/tools/sessions', data=form2)
print(response.url)
print(response.status_code)
print(response.ok)
r = s.get('http://bp-webtools1.otto.boreus.de/tools/it/reviews/v2/reviews?review_service_host=live') #this is the page where I find the form to fill and submit
print r.content
```

After logging in I should then fill a form in order to choose the dates of the reviews I'm interested in, submit it and scrape the results. I tried to apply  the same logic as above but I'm not able to make the post method work anymore.

If I use Chrome developers tools while filling and submitting the form I get this:

```
Request URL:http://bp-webtools1.otto.boreus.de/tools/it/reviews/v2/reviews/search_reviews?review_service_host=live
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:10.107.10.40:80
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Response Headers
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:text/javascript;charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 10 Jan 2018 10:59:53 GMT
Expires:Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache
Set-Cookie:_shoptools_session=UjcvTFQxMDdON2s4bmprb0JBZEhNeGc5b1VoT09TcUg3Z0I5OE9Ob2JhQzRPSkJPdDViTXlqaWxwV2JTZnNqS3Z6TExpL256ektmUWdCSEVDS2tYUkhTbXFFNGJ3ZzlrRzRRbWU5OWE3SWQzUjlQWllIb1RmVW02dFBFWDA4bkFpUHF3cURwZGt0OW8rK08yTXhXVlYyMExLVFh3bjhOMm04VDJhQjJONlJUWTczenQwV3FhMGxpVWw2QThwcmxwaElYZmFwQXdXbGVrWVk1S1h1Wk02a1lJdzk4NVdzczdmWmZpZHl3V0VkcWowMVAydVRMMWc2OEE4UXBwWFZLNy0tMU1TSUhXYkR4VHdQZ0tkUUk4Ykordz09--0ba74552e6a1ff0aefa92b641fec5ca3d1d93744; path=/; HttpOnly
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
X-Request-Id:dcab253c-1b74-447d-bba2-e5f4f626326e
X-Runtime:1.337000
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
Request Headers
Accept:*/*;q=0.5, text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:it-IT,it;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:1311
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:user_id=BAhpAmwU--b6aed621ab0867a3634a01cf398e861d40a306f4; _shoptools_session=RzhjWjdGOTZuNGV1WXluUnJsSGNDOFV1a1FzdFo1cm15bGExUS8zemhwOW92L1QyR1hkRGJKc25tUkFxSU00K2hYa3JMbFR0V3JHOE1reEExQ0ROb01OS3BlYUxTb3lpcjJLYkxBdW4zQlRzeHFpRmNDbmR1WjIvQ2Y1R2h2WWI4QXh2NituREFiVjJPRmJ4cGN3SUtiOHNEdnlBR3dYVFFOeHBuYjA0YUpsMWVMYW1Nbjg3SWZhSEo0UlUrekl3dHc0UlNNQUpLWkYyL1BQbDU1Y0lPOEZCR3FwSkgzdVBBZUdVWkdoa2g3NmRmdFMxeTh4dU1QeURnZ2hYYVl2bmg4eXdhcUZiRjIyTGxXUEFFQlRaZUw5U3I5cTFDazRFQUFVOWFsc0EwVWRYZm1DdXdUUXhhdFBUbzZzS2dTemxpM05EdnJGOGc4UXZVcmdDRitDbmNxeko2Z3puWUVFeUJleEVQblRvMjZJTVU5UWJYbVd3dVRUNTJ6T3ZoMXZLcTNZcVNLN2wwRVB4a2VzQStkUnMxdVZ4aDhVcEh0N0Urbng4OXFCNWJZMG9ZbTZmK0NiNDJYWWJyTUVQbEFrT2FMS2dMRVVLbUZ2K3JCSzdKc3ZHNkRvM0I4THRKTS91ZkV5TG1tRWxaRzE4b21PWUVQTE5UY3lRZzMrUWNpNEhGR1BvWXAzdU13WGNHWG1wQTRKVXJnYk4xNnRtMXB3QmNwTWxGdjVEcFpGK2Mybjh5eWUwTkIzYzV5c1hTNmptRkJxeENWVm8rN2NZcnoraGMxaUtqSXFkQVcvTDRGLzgyVlM2YUJNLzVEdGVqS1hVQW5VRkJtMXVNaTdqNWZBdGNnL3RYeENTVFVaK2tUS0JMY3Uyb1E9PS0tU01xem9VN2ZKWUE5S0RlUlZGN2hydz09--99e4617fce843b56f953710949378b98d8fd8575
Host:bp-webtools1.otto.boreus.de
Origin:http://bp-webtools1.otto.boreus.de
Referer:http://bp-webtools1.otto.boreus.de/tools/it/reviews/v2/reviews?review_service_host=live
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36
X-CSRFToken:IErrbmeMS3fR2c7olBjNCRuT3uH9u//1HmRixtccJ0UuB2nFirS1Y8nA/0VMrTBeGvM4ttpTQlCpzmSke/CRfg==
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Query String Parameters
review_service_host:live
Form Data
utf8:✓
reviews_review_search_presenter[userID]:5228
reviews_review_search_presenter[reserveYN]:F
reviews_review_search_presenter[timeOffset]:-60
reviews_review_search_presenter[aktiv]:alle
reviews_review_search_presenter[meinungstyp]:R
reviews_review_search_presenter[typus]:
reviews_review_search_presenter[minNote]:1
reviews_review_search_presenter[maxNote]:5
reviews_review_search_presenter[fromDate]:2017-01-01
reviews_review_search_presenter[fromTime]:00:00
reviews_review_search_presenter[toDate]:2017-01-01
reviews_review_search_presenter[toTime]:23:59
reviews_review_search_presenter[fromUpdateDate]:
reviews_review_search_presenter[fromUpdateTime]:
reviews_review_search_presenter[toUpdateDate]:
reviews_review_search_presenter[toUpdateTime]:
reviews_review_search_presenter[artikelNummer]:
reviews_review_search_presenter[masterStyleID]:
reviews_review_search_presenter[digiStyleID]:
reviews_review_search_presenter[id]:
reviews_review_search_presenter[text]:
reviews_review_search_presenter[ownClientOnlyYN]:false
reviews_review_search_presenter[accountNumber]:
reviews_review_search_presenter[name]:
reviews_review_search_presenter[firstName]:
reviews_review_search_presenter[email]:
```

I've tried to add this to my first script:

```
params={
    'reviews_review_search_presenter[userID]': '5228',
    'reviews_review_search_presenter[reserveYN]': 'F',
    'reviews_review_search_presenter[timeOffset]':'-60',
    'reviews_review_search_presenter[aktiv]':'alle',
    'reviews_review_search_presenter[meinungstyp]':'R',
    'reviews_review_search_presenter[typus]': '',
    'reviews_review_search_presenter[minNote]':'1',
    'reviews_review_search_presenter[maxNote]':'5',
    'reviews_review_search_presenter[fromDate]':'2017-01-01',
    'reviews_review_search_presenter[fromTime]':'00:00',
    'reviews_review_search_presenter[toDate]':'2017-01-01',
    'reviews_review_search_presenter[toTime]':'23:59',
    'reviews_review_search_presenter[fromUpdateDate]':'',
    'reviews_review_search_presenter[fromUpdateTime]':'',
    'reviews_review_search_presenter[toUpdateDate]':'',
    'reviews_review_search_presenter[toUpdateTime]':'',
    'reviews_review_search_presenter[artikelNummer]':'',
    'reviews_review_search_presenter[masterStyleID]':'',
    'reviews_review_search_presenter[digiStyleID]':'',
    'reviews_review_search_presenter[id]':'',
    'reviews_review_search_presenter[text]':'',
    'reviews_review_search_presenter[ownClientOnlyYN]':'false',
    'reviews_review_search_presenter[accountNumber]':'',
    'reviews_review_search_presenter[name]':'',
    'reviews_review_search_presenter[firstName]':'',
    'reviews_review_search_presenter[email]':'',
    }
response2 =s.post('http://bp-webtools1.otto.boreus.de/tools/it/reviews/v2/reviews/search_reviews?review_service_host=live', data=params)
print(response2.text)
print(response2.status_code)
```

but I get status code 500.

Any idea/hint on how proceed with the form would really be appreciated (for the scraping part I think I'll be ok). Please just consider that I'm not a specialist, so any reference to tutorials, web sources etc. will also be useful. I already searched on Stackoverflow for similar posts but I could'nt find anything that suits for my issue.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try sending all headers you see in 'Chrome developer tools' ...

Comment: Hi Maurice, I'm not sure I understood correctly your comment, all headers I see are already posted. ..

Comment: You need to send some headers back to the server. Usually that are Cookies, Tokens.... Review requests [docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers).

Comment: @MauriceMeyer thanks, got it but didn't work